# HELP. Cancel Site Collection Backup Job

Tags: sharepoint-server, backup

I attempted to backup a site collection through the GUI (Backup & Restore -> Site Collection Backup). When I pulled the size it was only 499MB or 0.49GB. However, my backup is now 50GB. How can I cancel the job? I do not see it running in the active jobs.

I don't see anywhere to pause/cancel this.

Comment: I have same issue with you today. The site collection just 40GB but the backup-spsite grow over 100GB. I have to stop it using by restart timer job. How did you backup the site collection at that time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go the `central admin > Monitoring > Check Job status` on this page look for the backup job(Site Collection Backup ). If it is still running, stop/ delete it.

Another way is on the server go to service console and stop the SharePoint Timer Service and start it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Waqas. I actually did this initially and I did see it there. I deleted it as there was no stop option but it appears to still be growing in size. I can try stopping the timer service.

Comment: did you recycle the timer service?

Comment: Just did. That appears to have work. Is this a common occurrence? Why would something like that happen??

Thank you, btw. Almost blew up my fileserver's storage.

Comment: Some times it happen, why file size is too big there are tons of issue with it. You can open another thread and give the details somebody else will help on it.

Comment: if this solve the issue, please mark it as answer and up vote so other will get benefits along me.

Comment: Waqas, I'm unable to upvote it but I will mark it as the answer. I believe I do not have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: No problem, it is ok...Once you get enough come back and vote for me...:)